# Не отображается часть кода из *.jsp в Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl

Использую IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate и Tomcat 9:

```
  <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Список всех резюме</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="fragments/header.jsp"/>
<section>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Имя</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${resumes}" var="resume">
            <jsp:useBean id="resume" type="ru.javawebinar.basejava.model.Resume"/>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="resume?uuid=${resume.uuid}">${resume.fullName}</a></td>
                <td>${resume.getContact(ContactType.MAIL)}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</section>
<jsp:include page="fragments/footer.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

При выводе через Tomcat в браузере не отображается код в цикле forEach:

```
<c:forEach items="${resumes}" var="resume">
        <jsp:useBean id="resume" type="ru.javawebinar.basejava.model.Resume"/>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="resume?uuid=${resume.uuid}">${resume.fullName}</a></td>
            <td>${resume.getContact(ContactType.MAIL)}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Все остальное отображается. Подскажите куда "копать": это ошибка в коде или в настройках проекта (может библиотеку какую надо подгрузить).

Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: Надо дебажить - что вы передаете в качестве коллекции. Может, там `null` приходит или пустая коллекция

Comment: уберите тег <jsp:useBean>